# XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD... No such file or directory Issue

Tags: 14.04, lamp, proftpd

I'm running command:-

```
sudo  /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Earlier it was working & i was able to run Magento projects using lampp.

but now when I'm running this command then getting following error due to which not able to run Magento projects:-

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.0.6-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD.../opt/lampp/lampp: line 197: /opt/lampp/var/proftpd/start.err: No such file or directory
fail.
```

**Note:-** It can be helpful :-

When i run command:-

```
sudo netstat -tunap | grep LISTEN
```

then getting following response:-

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1182/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1201/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2345/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      4534/httpd      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      2345/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN  

4534/httpd
```

After creating folder "proftpd" & file "start.err" manually issue has been resolved but now "Mysql Database"  has stopped working.

When i running :-

```
http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/
```

then getting some issue, you can check here:-

https://screenshots.firefox.com/LCup8PTKEGG2s0ll/localhost

I tried :-

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

But still getting same problem.

Please help me to resolve this issue **ASAP**

Comment: Does `/opt/lampp/var/proftpd/start.err` file exist?

Comment: so create it and give it the right permission as per the one your app is using!

Comment: after creating this file,content of this file will be  empty OR automatically wright ?how it has been deleted automatically?

Comment: Not sure about that but let me check that

Comment: even folder "proftpd"  doesn't exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81345/discussion-between-george-udosen-and-wakar-ahamad).

Comment: After a long afford,I didn't get success.finally reinstalled lampp.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I had limited power so could not help you further but I hope it went well